# Xcode debug warning about two-stage rotation animation

Tags: ios, xcode, rotation, warnings

My iPad app outputs the following warning in xcode debugger below using (gcc). 
It's very frustrating because I don't know how to debug it.

```
Using two-stage rotation animation. To use the smoother single-stage animation, this application must remove two-stage method implementations.
```

I do use following method for rotation changes

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{

    //with conditional statement like 

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){

    //change images for portrait, redisplay any visible popovers

    }else{

    //change images for landscape, redisplay any visible popovers

    }
```

I'm not using any older two stage methods.

The app does use a root tabbarController with two viewControllers and one navigationController tabs in it.
Any help would be great.

Comment: I'm starting to suspect this is not a real warning or an older version byproduct as I am not getting it when I use a different mac with another iPad all running the latest xcode 4.3.3 and iPad iOS 5.1 (warning was on xcode 4.2 with iOS 4.3)  ...May answer this myself more to let others who might also come across this weird one.

Answer (score 0):

May not be a real warning or an older version byproduct as I am not getting warning when I use a different mac with another iPad all running the latest xcode 4.3.3 and iPad iOS 5.1 (warning was on xcode 4.2 with iOS 4.3)

Also note these warning were only appearing when running on the device itself and not in simulator.

Hope that helps someone else.